# How do I delete map instance?

Tags: c++

```
map<long long, vector<SoundInfo *> > DataCenter::getCopySoundListMap(){

    lock();

    map<long long, vector<SoundInfo *> > copyMap(m_soundListMap);

    unLock();

    return copyMap;
}
```

I have this method. It makes a copy of map and returns the copy.

I am calling this method like this

```
map<long long, vector<SoundInfo *> > copyMap = DataCenter::getInstance()->getCopySoundListMap();
```

After I am done with it at the end of the function, I did something like this

```
delete copyMap;
```

And it complains that this is not a pointer.. I know that this is not a pointer then I was wondering when the instance of the copied map is going to be released.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It will be released at the end of the function, when `copyMap` passes out of scope. Why did you ask about such a complicated example of a simple principle?

Comment: @Beta: it's understandable that something seemingly "exotic" (at least to someone from a C background) like `map` might not be intuitively understood to have behaviours as simple as an `int` or `std::string`... but of course it does! Long live value semantics :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a local variable, so it gets released when it goes out of scope... that is, when the `{`...`}` block it's inside reaches that `}`.  It doesn't matter whether it's a function scope, a `for` or `while` loop, just an arbitrarily blocked group of statements... the variables introduced inside that block have their destructors invoked at the end.  The memory for the map object itself comes from the stack, and is reclaimed for use by further variables, perhaps locals from other functions that are called.  That map object - while non-empty - will have pointers into heap memory as well, they'll be released during destruction.

Comment: To clarify: memory for the map root comes from the stack, but the map will probably have heap objects as well, all of which are correctly freed when the map goes out of scope.

Comment: @Dietrich: yes... just reread over my answer and edited to explain that, then saw your comment.  :-)